# Preventing shrinking of objects in a layout when making a program using PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qgroupbox

I tried to build a simple program using PyQt5 but got a problem.
There is a QScrolArea, to which a QVBoxLayout is set. And several QGroupBox objects are set inside the QVBoxLayout.
I briefly describe the structure at the below simple code and picture(a). But the problem occurs when the main window size is reduced. When the main window size is reduced, every object inside QScrollArea(or QVBoxLayout) shrinks and overlaps to each other just like picture(b). This makes my program ugly. I want to every QGroupBox object be shown like picture(c). Do I miss something? Please share your knowledge and idea how to avoid this objects shrinking and overapping problem.

```
QScrollArea = QVBoxLayout() 
QScrollArea.addWidget(QGroupBox1)
QScrollArea.addWidget(QGroupBox2)
QScrollArea.addWidget(QGroupBox3)
```

[image]

[image]  --> [image]

Comment: Have you tried setting a minimum size on the QGroupBoxes? See [`minimumSize`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#minimumSize-prop).

Comment: I had. But if I set minimumSize for each QGroupBoxes, they do not shrink but still overlap to each other.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] in form of python code (if you're creating the layout programmatically) or eventually the UI file contents.